# Converting object "0.88923" to an integer. I always get zero

Tags: php, string, object

I am retrieving an object from an XML feed the value of which is "0.88923". I need to perform a calculation with this "number", but no matter what I try:

```
$rate = $nodes[0]['rate']; //(Get the "number" in this case 0.88923)

//Try to convert string (object) to integer, have tried all of these....
$rate = floatval($rate); //Yields 0
$rate = number_format($rate); //Yields 0
$rate = floatval($rate); //Yields 0
```

I can achieve integers, but always zero. Most frustrating!

UPDATE: var_dump gives me:

> object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) { [0]=> string(7) "0.88923" }

My exact code (using at the moment a suggestion below) is:

```
 $xref  = simplexml_load_file('http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml');
 $nodes = $xref->xpath('//*[@currency="GBP"]');

 //Current best suggestion below, but still not working
 $rate = floatval(strip_tags($nodes[0]['rate']->asXML()));

 if (ctype_digit($rate)) {
   echo "The string $rate consists of all digits.\n";
 } else {
   echo "The string $rate does not consist of all digits.\n";
 }  

 $calc = 1/$rate;

 echo $calc; //Should be about 1.13
```

Comment: `floatval("0.5")` is working perfectly - make sure that your input is correct. What do you get when you `var_dump($nodes[0]['rate'])`?

Comment: Your code [works fine](https://eval.in/892863) your input must be not 0.5

Comment: `var_dump((int)"0.99", (int)"",(int)"xxx",(int)null);` - you can get zero, because input is float less than 1.0 or is not a number

Comment: Sorry @Connum, I have a two year old girl here while I code mate :) var_dump gives: 
object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) { [0]=> string(7) "0.88923" }

Comment: @Accountant م - In fairness the actual output was 0.88923, I simplified for the question and cannot think that would make a difference.

Comment: var_dump shows that your $rate is actually an array, not number. So you need to do `$rate = $nodes[0]['rate'][0];` Also if you need answer to be an integer use [round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php), [ceil](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) or [floor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) according to your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `__toString()` on the rate to get the string content, then convert it to a float (not integer as written initially in the question) via `floatval()`:

```
<?php
$xref  = simplexml_load_file('http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml');
$nodes = $xref->xpath('//*[@currency="GBP"]');

// get contents as string, then convert to float:
$rate = floatval($nodes[0]['rate']->__toString());

$calc = 1/$rate;

echo $calc; //Should be about 1.13
```

Comment: I do not have access to __toString and I am afraid the other solutions are not working. I am checking with:     if (ctype_digit($rate)) {
        echo "The string $rate consists of all digits.\n";
    } else {
        echo "The string $rate does not consist of all digits.\n";
    } which continues to insist $rate is not a number :(

Comment: Could you provide a very simplified example of your XML markup and the PHP lines where you load it into SimpleXML?

Comment: Sorry Connum I do not have __toString() available, could you please show another method

Comment: Updated my answer with a working example. What do you mean by not having `__toString()` available?` Is there any error message? Might be a problem with the PHP version in use being too old - what version are you on?

Comment: Sorry Connum I think before edit you may have uised one underscore, and it errored, and I assumed it was a newer (PHP 7) function I do not have. It is now working! I assume here then the "problem" was that this was not a string...it was an object (I am unclear on difference) and that I did not want an integer, I wanted a float!

Comment: Correct, it was a SimpleXMLElement object, from which you have to get the string first. :) Glad it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `round($rate);` It should round correctly!
Here's an example: https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_math_round

Comment: Why do you think OP wants to round the input? As the question reads, OP wants to do a type conversion from string to float.

Comment: "Try to convert string (object) to integer"

Comment: Not sure how I managed to miss that! ^^ Maybe got distracted by the use of `floatval()` twice. Still not sure if that's what the OP wants and what the problem is...